# as salamu alaykom wa rahmatu allah barakato, my name is ahmad im 13 and my question is alot of sheikhs say "modern music is haram"

Tags: music

and i want to know what they mean by "modern music" I know it means new music but do they mean old music was good if yes then what did old music consist of and what was good about it and could it still make you sin?